# When are items in an amp-list displayed

Tags: amp-html

If I use an `amp-list` to display a fairly large list of data (for example as shown below) will the first items in the list be displayed before the last one is loaded, or will it download the whole JSON list before displaying any of it? If the latter, what is the best way to get the first items displayed more quickly?

Example:

```
<amp-list width="auto" height="300" layout="fixed-height" src="https://jsondata.myurl.com">
    <template type="amp-mustache">
        <div>{{field1}} and {{field2}}</div>
    </template>
</amp-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I afraid that amp-list starts to load only after the whole JSON response is received and then it starts to display items one by one depending on which got his data(image for example) first. And if your page is already cached by Google your first loading result would be the same all times. So, my conclusion is that you can't influence on loading precedence, at least so far. Hope I'm right and it will help you.

Comment: Thank you!  Could I use the `amp-list` to load just minimal information, and then use an ID loaded by the `amp-list` to set variables that would cause other amp controls inside the list to be loaded?

Comment: Maybe I did not understand your question but if you want to get extra information about your item after a basic information was loaded I you have to have one more amp-list for each item inside your main list and some event to invoke extra information request,  it can be action like click on some button. Also you can use form instead of a list but concept is the same

Comment: I did not state it very clearly.  I need to display everything without additional user action, but I thought I might achieve the async loading I want (i.e. the first item is visible before the last one is loaded) if I used an `amp-list` to load just a skeleton first, with the `amp-list` causing `amp-binds` that would load all the details of each item in the `amp-list`.  Would those `amp-binds` then be asynchronous from each other, achieving the result I want?

Comment: You can use amp-bind only with already loaded data, so it wouldn't give any benefit in your case